# Cannot connect to MS SQL from IIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-core-2.2

I'm developing a .net core application. I have local SQL server. When I debug application from Visual Studio, it works great. But when I publish app to folder and want to run it from IIS, it cannot connect to database.

From database I found this error messages for failed logins:

Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.

FCB::Open failed: Could not open file C:\Users\p4too\AppData\Local\Temp\VS11CodeIndex\Microsoft.VsCodeIndex_86bc9b9e_7c02_4fe0_9598_c87ac2dd85db.mdf for file number 0.  OS error: 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

I was looking for that file, but I did not found even folder VS11CodeIndex.

I use
Entity framework core 2.2.4
SQL Server Management Studio                        15.0.18118.0

Comment: I added ef version, but I think problem is in sql server or OS.

Comment: We can't help without a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved the problem for me... you need to open C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config in Notepad and add setProfileEnvironment="true" to your AppPool.

In IIS, configure the app pool to run under an account with permissions to the DB on the server (advanced options of the app pool)
In the advanced option of the app pool, set Load User Profile to true